# How to use Mechanize to fill out form?

Tags: python, html, forms, mechanize

I am trying to make a script on Python that autofills a form on this [website](http://yeezy.shoezgallery.com/) form using Mechanize. The script should be able to loop and create unlimited entries on the form since there is no Capatcha.

Although, I am fairly new to Python and Mechanize, I know the basics and know HTML fairly well but am still looking for help.

If any of you could help I would greatly appreciate it.

This is what I have so far...

```
            import mechanize

            #This bot allows for autofill on the ShoezGallery Raffle.

            browser = mechanize.Browser()

            response = br.open("http://yeezy.shoezgallery.com/")

            br.addheaders = [("User-agent","Mozilla/5.0")] 

            url = "http://yeezy.shoezgallery.com/"

            browser.select_form(nr=0)

            browser.form['nom'] = Last name 

            browser.form['prenom'] = First Name

            browser.form['mail'] =  my email here

            browser.form['telephone'] = phone number here

            browser.form['taille'] = 4313

            browser.form['pays'] = Etats_Unis

            brower.submit()

            response = browser.open('http://yeezy.shoezgallery.com/')

            print response.read()
```

**EDIT**
The code format change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is doing **last** things **first** and you have mixed `browser` and `br`

```
 browser = mechanize.Browser()
 response = br.open("http://yeezy.shoezgallery.com/")
```

should be

```
 br = mechanize.Browser()
 br.addheaders = [("User-agent","Mozilla/5.0")] 
 response = br.open(url)
```

Read [pythonforbeginners.com/mechanize/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/mechanize/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet)  and follow the example code on this site.